# What exactly is the Axis2 scope in Property mediators in WSO2 esb?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

What exactly is the Axis2 scope in Property mediators in WSO2 esb?

There does not seem to be enough documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

scope defines the message context you will be accessing by default it is the Synapse message context. If you define the scope as axis2, then you will be accessing the axis2 message context.